# Make Plugging architecture in mvc c#

Tags: model-view-controller, plugins, architecture

hello  i want to develop plugging based architecture with mvc c# webapplication like wordpress if we import zip file then they have all attribute like create table, change User interface all those thing

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i Want to Develop Plugin System For mvc c# for Web Application i can use for Dynamic Page Content, in short my own Custom CMS

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask